# Copy from Evernote to Paste to Wordpress preserving formating

Tags: formatting, wordpress, evernote

Is it possible to post texts directly from the Windows desktop Evernote application to Wordpress, and retain the formating? Simple copy/past leads to format break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I didn't find the solution. It's possible to post to Facebook and Twitter, but not to Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight and copy the text from evernote, then use the "Press This" bookmarklet--the built-in posting function that comes with WP.  Formatting and links looked fine for me.
Peter