# WordPress and EverNote integration, any existing solutions?

Tags: sync, wordpress, evernote

Actually the tag and category system in WordPress and EverNote are very similar, almost exactly the same.

- We can create a **notebook/notebook group** in EverNote, its counterpart in Wordpress is **Category/Sub Category**
- We can mutiple **tag** any note in EverNote, similarly we can **tag** any post in Wordpress as well!

Since the two are so similar to each other in categorizing the article, I am wondering whether there is a **existing solution** to automatically convert between the two.

Like one click to post my EverNote note to WordPress under the **same category and same tag**. Or pull down my WordPress article to my EverNote account under the **same category and same tag**.

Preferably it can also handle image\video uploading issues as well. :)

I saw a similar questions asked years ago: [Posting from evernote to wordpress](https://superuser.com/questions/274497/posting-from-evernote-to-wordpress) So I was wondering is there any new update for this idea right now?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried [ifttt.com](http://ifttt.com) (read if this then that)? It allow you to create automated workflow between several web based services. ifttt can detect tag and category from WP and create notes within a specific notebook or tags. Might be worth the try.